# Cant Uninstall 14.04 and Reinstall 12.04

Tags: 14.04, uninstall

I upgraded to 14.04 a few days ago and would like to go back to 12.04 LTS for a while longer only thing is that now when I insert my 12.04 startup disc and reboot my computer its not booting the live cd. It just goes to the encypted passphrase login screen (I encrypted my disk and home folder on installation of 14.04) After I put in my passwords I see the cd/dvd drive is in use. I even clicked on the wubi.exe file and asked for help booting from cd. It installs something and then asks to reboot. I do that and it just goes back to the login page. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

First ensure that your BIOS is set to boot from the CD.

Comment: Ok. How can I do that?

Comment: It's very dependent on the particular computer.  When you restart a message usually appears briefly telling you to press a key (F1, ESC, or something) to enter the BIOS.  Then there is usually a menu system, you need to search through the options till you find how to set the boot device order.  Ensure that the CD drive is listed first.

Use care when changing BIOS options, mistakes can be very serious.